# Attachments on iPad in iFrame docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am using iframe to get document signed by clients on ipad. There are attachments as well for each signer, but before attaching the captured image, I want to resize it. Is there a way to resize an image before attaching it with document.

Comment: I'm not clear on your question, what do you mean when you ask if you can re-size the image?  Let's say a recipient attaches a 300 x 300 pixel PNG file, are you asking if you can re-size that PNG as part of the signing process?

Comment: Yes, I want to resize the image to an appropriate level. because if recipient uses ipad's camera to attach an image, then image size is quite big. I want to resize that image to an appropriate level before it is attached with document.

Comment: I've posted an answer for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no functionality built in to the DocuSign platform that would allow the re-sizing of an attached image, DocuSign is an eSignature company and when they allow attachments on top of the documents that are about to be signed they should not be modified in any way as it could alter important aspects about the legally binding agreement that is being signed.

However I think you might still have a few options here to solve your issue.  The two obvious ones that come to mind are:

- Get the captured image from your recipients BEFORE they start the signing process.
- Use a conditional tab to not allow the recipient to add an attachment unless it's within a certain size.

For the first solution you could use the **Embedding** feature to design whatever UI around the signing experience you'd like and in that case you can control the order of operations (i.e. have them upload the image first before clicking a button to sign) and you can then resize the image and add it to the envelope.

For the second solution, you could use the *radioGroupTabs* to add 2 grouped radio buttons to the envelope (so that only one can be checked) and say something like "Check this box if your image is within NxM size" and then the signer attachment tab only shows if they check that box.  To do this you can make use of the **ConditionalTabs** feature.

For more information on Embedding DocuSign please see this page from the DocuSign Developer Center:

[Embedding Feature](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#Embedding)

For more information on Conditional Fields refer to the User Guide (non-api use) and the documentation:

[Conditional Fields User Guide](http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Quick%20Start%20-%20Using%20Conditional%20Fields.pdf)

[REST API Guide (search for term "conditional")](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm)